# get latest/max for each partition key

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The table is pretty simple a package with a list of components with the package name as partition key and version as sort key.

As the title suggests I have a need to get the latest version of each package but cant quiet grapple how best/most efficient way to achieve this?

I've had the thought of using a date-time stamp as the sort key(version) or as a GSI along with version number, but the best I can see is that you would have to repeatedly query the table for each partition that returns you an ordered list?

I have also considered the possibility of using a second table to store this info.

Interested on other opinions on how best to tackle this. any hints how to do it with spring-data-dynamo/Java would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is a [Sparse Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html). Basically you can create an attribute like `isLatestVersion` that is either `true` or else the item doesn’t have that attribute. Then, you can create a GSI with that attribute as either the partition key or the sort key. Only items that have that attribute present will appear in the GSI, so you can scan the GSI very quickly. Or, if you use `isLatestVersion` as the partition key of the GSI, then you can query the GSI very easily (I.e. something like get the latest version of all packages starting with “Foo” might be useful... but I don’t know your other use cases).

Here’s the catch. You need to make sure that when you add a new version, you remove the attribute from the previous latest version. That’s easy enough to do using [DynamoDB Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) and a Lambda function, or you could use [DynamoDB TransactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html) to add the new package version to your table at the same time as you remove the attribute from the older version, but you do need to carefully consider all the cases where the latest version can change.

Either way, you need to design your application code to filter out the occasional duplicate entry for a package. (GSIs are eventually consistent, so there’s a very short window of time (typically a few milliseconds) after you update the latest version where it’s possible that if you query for the latest package version, you might get the two latest versions.)

Comment: currently trying to get it to work with sparse index's, looks like it should work for this. though currently spring data is always trying to scan instead of query on the GSI of isLatestVersion.

Comment: This is what I needed! Sparse Index is so easy to forget about!